# Swift - How to properly use delegate

Tags: ios, swift, salesforce-ios-sdk

I am using Salesforce ios sdk for my mobile application and there is a method to execute SOQL queries. For eg.,

```
class SfdcController: NSObject, SFRestDelegate {   
    let request = SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().request(forQuery:"SELECT Name FROM User LIMIT 10");
    SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().send(request, delegate: self);

    func request(_ request: SFRestRequest, didLoadResponse jsonResponse: Any)
    {
        print(jsonResponse)
    }

    func request(_ request: SFRestRequest, didFailLoadWithError error: Error)
    {
       self.log(.debug, msg: "didFailLoadWithError: \(error)")
    }
}
```

**Question**
I'll execute multiple SOQL queries with in the same class and there are different methods to handle the response. Now,

- Is there a way to get the reference of the request inside the `didLoadResponse`? So, I can write switch statement to execute different functions.
- If cannot reuse the delegate, do I need to create multiple delegate class to handle each and every response?

What is the better way to do it?

**Update**

request

```
SFRestRequest 0x1700cb130 
endpoint: /services/data 
method: GET 
path: /v39.0/sobjects/Event/describe 
queryParams: []
```

Other way to delegate is to create a separate class and define it.

```
SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().send(objectDescribe, delegate: testing());


class testing: NSObject, SFRestDelegate {

    func request(_ request: SFRestRequest, didLoadResponse jsonResponse: Any) {
        print(jsonResponse)
    }
}
```

But the problem with the above, I have to create a class every time when I want to execute a SOQL query.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure their api but can you distinguish from the request object that being return the delegate functions? It might has path or query so it can tell which request was??

Comment: @HMHero I have updated the question. No, the `request` doesn't contain any reference.

Comment: Then can you cache the request into array or variable and compare in the callback? I don't like the idea.

Comment: `Is there a way to get the reference of the request inside the didLoadResponse? So, I can write switch statement to execute different functions.`  Is there not a reference of some sort in the `jsonResponse` that you could switch on?

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea for you.  Create a separate delegate class and in that class put an identifier. Then let that separate class delegate back to your view controller.

```
// Create a protocol for it
class SFHandlerDelegate {
    func request(_ request: SFRestRequest, handlerId: Int, didLoadResponse jsonResponse: Any)
    func request(_ request: SFRestRequest, handlerId: Int, didFailLoadWithError error: Error)
}
```

Make a new delegate class

```
// this becomes the SF delegate
class SFHandler : SFRestDelegate {
    var id: Int = 0
    delegate: SFHandlerDelegate
    init(id: Int, delegate: SFHandlerDelegate) { 
        self.id = id 
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    func request(_ request: SFRestRequest, didLoadResponse jsonResponse: Any)
    {
        delegate.request(request, handlerId: id, didLoadResponse: jsonResponse)
    }

    func request(_ request: SFRestRequest, didFailLoadWithError error: Error)
    {
        delegate.request(request, handlerId: id, didFailLoadWithError: error)
    }

}
```

Change the controller

```
class SfdcController: NSObject, SFHandlerDelegate {   
    let request = SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().request(forQuery:"SELECT Name FROM User LIMIT 10");
    let delegate = SFHandlerDelegate(self, 123) // use some handler id
    SFRestAPI.sharedInstance().send(request, delegate: delegate);

    func request(_ request: SFRestRequest, handlerId: Int, didLoadResponse jsonResponse: Any)
    {
        switch handlerId {
            case 123:
                doSomething()
            // whatever
        }
        print(jsonResponse)
    }

    func request(_ request: SFRestRequest, handlerId: Int, didFailLoadWithError error: Error)
    {
         switch handlerId {
            case 123:
                doSomething()
            // whatever
         }
         self.log(.debug, msg: "didFailLoadWithError: \(error)")
    }
}
```